# How to use cpx when debugging in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-debugger

I want to use [cpx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx) as a background task for one of my debugging configurations inside Visual Studio Code. However it has no output and causes this error:
[image: The task 'npm: cpx' cannot be tracked.]

Since cpx does it's job in less then a second I don't need it to be tracked. Is there a way to tell VS Code just to run the task and not track it?

Here's my `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "script": "cpx",
            "type": "npm",
            "isBackground": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the task only once, just set `isBackground: false`.

Otherwise, before Visual Studio Code launches debugger, it needs to know when background task has completed its initial job. It happens by watching task output with problem matcher but, as you have pointed out, cpx by default does not output anything. Here's my suggestion:

1. Pass `--verbose` flag to cpx which gives us some output ending with `Be watching...`
2. Use following problem matcher with your task:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "script": "cpx",
            "type": "npm",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": {
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true, // monitoring should happen immediately after start
                    "beginsPattern": "^whatever", // irrelevant
                    "endsPattern": "^Be watching.*"  // pattern indicating that task is done
                },
                // we don't need pattern section but it's required by the schema.
                "pattern": [
                    {
                        "regexp": "^whatever",
                        "file": 1,
                        "location": 2,
                        "message": 3
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```